# Is true that if $f(x)=\prod_{k=1}^nF_k(x)$ then $f'(x)=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{F'_j}{F_j}\prod_{k=1}^nF_k(x)$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm going to use this formula but I don't sure if this is true, I reached that conclusion one day but I didn't proof it.

Comment: It is true. It is a generalization of the product rule.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=\prod_{j}F_j(x)$$
If $f(x)$ is nonzero for all $x$, we have that
$$\ln f(x)=\sum_{j}\ln F_j(x)$$
so that 
$$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\sum_{j}\frac{F_j'(x)}{F_j(x)}.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: There's really no need to introduce logarithms here. And what if some $F_j$ are negative?

Comment: @RobertIsrael If $F_j$ are negative, use the complex logarithm. I decided to take the logarithm approach instead of induction because it's quicker.

Comment: But then the equation for $\ln f$ is only true up to a multiple of $2 \pi i$ (which of course doesn't matter when you take the derivative).

Comment: @RobertIsrael That is very true, but for the OP's intents and purposes, that may not matter at all. The OP's posts seem to all indicate that they are in a calculus class, and that the dteails of complex analysis are deemed unimportant.

Comment: Students in calculus classes are often told that the logarithm of a negative number is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all the $F_j$ are nonzero, it is true.  You can prove it by induction on $n$.